# Can we dump database of db-synch and use it for initialising a fresh db-synch instance?

Tags: cardano-db-sync

Db-sync takes about 48 hours to follow the tip, starting from a fresh installation fully. Is there a way to improve the sync time? Is it possible to dump the database and transfer it to a fresh installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the official snapshots, provided by IOHK. Just restore them after setting up the database.

They are usually linked in the release description on Github: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/releases

You will find a link to the list of snapshots, grouped by schema version.

As of today, the current schema version is 11 and the list of snapshots are listed here: https://update-cardano-mainnet.iohk.io/cardano-db-sync/index.html#11/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dump the PostgreSQL directly, as `cardano-db-sync` depends on other states as well.

[You need to use the `cardano-db-tool`](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/state-snapshot.md) to take and restore the snapshot.